# Date comparison in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, date

I am trying to insert a record in mysql table if the id and date are not existing but using the following stored procedure the record get inserted even if the record already exists.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Add`(Id int,Date_In varchar(50), Date_In2 varchar(50), Out result int)
BEGIN
IF (select count(*) from mytable Where date_format(Datein, '%d/%m/%Y')=str_to_date(Date_In2, '%d/%m/%Y') and id=Id) < 1 then
BEGIN
... insert statement here          
set result=1;
END;
END if;
end
```

The date from JSP page is dd/MM/yyyy format.

Java:

```
String date2 = request.getParameter("date");
//15/05/2015
insert statement goes here
```

How can I find if the date already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date comparison is wrong

```
date_format(Datein, '%d/%m/%Y') <= str_to_date(Date_In2, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

The statement will return 0 , using `str_to_date` function will return the date in `Y-m-d` format unless its again formatted to a different format using `date_format`  function.

```
mysql> select date_format(curdate(), '%d/%m/%Y')=str_to_date('04/05/2015', '%d/%m/%Y') ;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| date_format(curdate(), '%d/%m/%Y')=str_to_date('04/05/2015', '%d/%m/%Y') |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                        0 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

And hence it fails.

If Datein is stored as `date` datatype no need to do format else you need to format as `Y-m-d`

```
mysql> select date_format(curdate(), '%Y-%m-%d')=str_to_date('04/05/2015', '%d/%m/%Y') ;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| date_format(curdate(), '%Y-%m-%d')=str_to_date('04/05/2015', '%d/%m/%Y') |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                        1 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)



date_format(Datein, '%Y-%m-%d')=str_to_date(Date_In2, '%d/%m/%Y')
```